# Elasticsearch script query involving root and nested values

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I have a simplified Organization document with nested publication values like so (ES 2.3):

```
{ 
  "organization" : { 
    "dateUpdated" : 1395211600000,

    "publications" : [ 
      { 
        "dateCreated" : 1393801200000
      },
      { 
        "dateCreated" : 1401055200000
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to find all Organizations that have a publication dateCreated < the organization's dateUpdated:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "publications",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "script": {
                "script": "doc['publications.dateCreated'].value < doc['dateUpdated'].value"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that when I perform a nested query, the nested query does not have access to the root document values, so `doc['dateUpdated'].value` is invalid and I get 0 hits.

Is there a way to pass in a value into the nested query? Or is my nested approach completely off here? I would like to avoid creating a separate document just for publications if necessary.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting-fields.html
Stored fields — fields explicitly marked as "store": true — can be accessed using the _fields['field_name'].value or _fields['field_name'].values syntax.

Comment: Maybe you can try this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not access the root values from nested query context. They are indexed as separate documents. From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-query.html)

> The nested clause “steps down” into the nested comments field. It **no**
>   longer has access to fields in the root document, nor fields in any
>   other nested document.

You can get the desired results with the help of [copy_to](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) parameter. Another way to do this would be to use *include_in_parent* or *include_in_root* but they might be [deprecated](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/12461) in future and it will also increase the index size as every field of nested type will be included in root document so in this case `copy_to` functionality is better.

This is a sample index

```
PUT nested_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "blogpost": {
      "properties": {
        "rootdate": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "copy_of_nested_date": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "comments": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "nested_date": {
              "type": "date",
              "copy_to": "copy_of_nested_date"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here every value of *nested_date* will be copied to *copy_of_nested_date* so copy_of_nested_date will look something like [1401055200000,1393801200000,1221542100000] and then you could use simple query like this to get the results.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": "doc['rootdate'].value < doc['copy_of_nested_date'].value"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You don't have to change your nested structure but you would have to **reindex** the documents after adding `copy_to` to *publication dateCreated*