# Elasticsearch cannot access `doc` inside script that has nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, elasticsearch-dsl

Using ES 2.3.3
A section of my document mapping is as follows :

```
"rents": {
  "type": "nested",
  "properties": {.........e.g. "avg"}
},
"location": {
    "type": "geo_point"
}
```

And in script, I try to find distance of this field

```
 {
  "nested": {
    "path": "rents",
    "query": {
      "function_score": {
        "query": {...some rents queries....},
        "functions": [
          { 
            "script_score": {
              "params": {
                "center_lat": 23.509518,
                "center_long":-18.378842
              },
              "script": "return doc['location'].distanceInMiles(center_lat, center_long)*rents.avg;"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but this keeps throwing error:

```
"reason": {
  "type": "script_exception",
  "reason": "failed to run inline script [return doc['location'].distanceInMiles(center_lat, center_long)*rents.avg;] using lang [groovy]",
  "caused_by": {
    "type": "null_pointer_exception",
    "reason": null
  }
}
```

I am following the guide https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/modules-scripting.html#_document_fields then what am I doing wrong? Please note all my documents have `location` field, none of them are null or empty. It seems `doc` is not available in my above script.

Please note even if I remove `rents.avg` from the script error remains there. So my suspicion is `doc` is not available inside `path: rents` ? If so then how to get it work?

Comment: You can not access the root values from nested query context, you could refer to my answer to similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40095499/elasticsearch-script-query-involving-root-and-nested-values/40098750#40098750), you would have to include avg values in root document with copy_to param. Let me know if it does not work out

Comment: Thank you @ChintanShah25 for the suggestion. Unfortunately changing mapping and re-indexing is not an available option for me. I appreciate your help!